# How do I make a local branch track a remote branch with a different name?

Tags: git

I have a setup with two servers (staging and production). Both of these has a master branch I can push to (I use heroku, not that it matters though).

Currently, I can push to staging with this command:

```
git push staging master
```

Which will push my local `master` branch. However, I would like to have a local branch named `staging`, which will push to the remote repository `staging/master`. How can this be done?

Comment: Just as a side note, I wrote a [blog post](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2010/08/website-maintenance-with-git-the-pro-way.html) about managing staging and production servers with git; I don't know if it might be relevant to you or to someone else reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it manually,

```
git push staging staging:master
```

I'd suggest maybe setting up a configuration that would allow you to do it automatically, though:

```
git config remote.staging.push refs/heads/staging:refs/heads/master
```

which tells git to push the local `staging` branch to `master` on the remote side (i.e. the staging remote) (if I remember the syntax correctly), and optionally

```
git config branch.staging.remote staging
```

which will tell git that if you have `staging` checked out and just type `git push`, it should push to the `staging` remote.

Of course I think you can do this using `git branch` and `git remote`, but I just went through the process of creating a similar setup (2 servers) and I found it easier to just work with the configurations directly.

Answer (score 3):

#### To always push to tracking:

First, make sure the config option `push.default` is set to `tracking`:

```
git config push.default tracking
```

Second, set the upstream for your local branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream <localbranch> <remotename>/<remotebranch>
```

#### To only push one particular branch to a particular *different* remote branch

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the default push behavior (push all branches to matching on remote), you could just individually tell Git that when pushing to that particular remote, your local branch actually "matches" a different one on the remote:

```
git config remote.<remotename>.push refs/heads/<localbranch>:refs/heads/<remotebranch>
```

For more details on Git configuration options, see here:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config